# how to sort a string into string arr

Tags: java, string, parsing

```
String st = "1 2 3 -1 0 9 76 65 f0rest Neo Get_Right";

String[] sArr = st.split(" ");

Arrays.sort(sArr);
```

Then used a `HashMap`, add those elements by freq, but output is not as expected. Should I override `compareTo()`?

Output should be like :

```
-1 - 1

0 - 1

1 - 1

2 - 3

3 - 1

8 - 3

9 - 2

f0rest - 1

Get_Right - 1

Neo - 1
```

Comment: If you could go ahead and format your code that'd be great!

Comment: how does input relate to output? eg Get_Right

Comment: It is not clear what is you question and how exactly did you get your results.  Posting some code might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your array will be sorted according to the natural ordering of `String`s. If you don't like how these are ordered then yes, you should create a class that implements `Comparable` to sort them according to your implementation of the `compareTo` method.

I would suggest using a `List<YourObject>` where `YourObject` implements `Comparable` and then doing `Collections.sort(yourList)`.